# Moodle - Home layout com uma coluna

Tags: moodle

Olá,

Gostaria de saber como deixo somente minha home page com uma coluna só (coluna de conteúdo), quero tirar o `<aside>` da esquerda (bloco administração).

Única forma que consegui chegar mais perto disso foi alterar o arquivo `columns3.php` colocando um span12 na `div`do conteúdo, isso fez com que ela ocupasse todo layout jogando o `<aside>` para baixo. Mas acho que não é correto fazer isso né?

Tenho outra opção?

**Como esta** 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como gostaria**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

basta eu apontar no `config.php` qual arquivo php vc quer usar nessa pagina, ai vc pode personalizar esse arquivo do jeito que quer.

No meu caso ficou assim:

```
// My dashboard page.
    'mydashboard' => array(
        'file' => 'frontpage.php',
        'regions' => array(),
        'options' => array('nonavbar'=>true),
    ),
```

Usei no dashboard que é a tela que vc é direcionado após o login o arquivo frontpage.php  mas posso criar outro arquivo.php e programador do jeito que vc quiser.